# How can I debug runtime error for scipy solver in python

Tags: python, scipy, model, solver, pyomo

hello I get this runtime error when I run my code in pyomo environ using scipy solver.
I'm using it to solve a MINLP example
.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2W48.png)

this is my error:

RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "scipy"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
executable: scipy
type: scipy
_args: ()
options: {}

How can I debug it?

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: At the very least quote the error, and show the scily function call that lroduced it

Comment: `scipy` has various `solvers`, but is not a 'solver'. You'll have to provide more context, including the documentation or tutorial that you are following.

Comment: i wrote the error

Comment: (Having not much used scipy recently) i'm 99.9% sure there is no MINLP solver in scipy! And although your problem could be interpreted as MILP and scipy's (modern) LP-solver base (HiGHS) currently adding MILP support, i'm 99% sure it's not yet available / wrapper / supported. If that's whats breaking or something earlier, well... i guess it doesn't matter much as the final result will be the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.